# Does this UIBarButton exists by default in iOS? How is it called

Tags: ios, uikit, uibarbuttonitem

I think I've seen this kind of button before, and now I need one.

A button like the one below who's label can be changed to whatever number I need (from 2 to 10 for example).

[image]

I have a feeling that this exists by default in iOS SDK but I can't seem to find it.

Does it exist by default or do I have to create it myself?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its easy to replicate.  Add a new RoundRectButton in interface builder, then in the attributes inspector change the type to Custom.  Set the BackgroundImage to an image similar to above, and then set the Title to the number.  By default the title will centered in the button, but you can use the Inset options in the attributes inspector and nudge the title in and down using the Top and Left inset attributes.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not a default item as far as I know. You can see all the default items in the [Apple Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW1) (see "System-Provided Buttons and Icons").